# Can someone tell me the regular expression for this?

Tags: regex

I am working with regular expressions, I need to create an expression for validating strings against the following scenario:

```
Solution.<word1|word2|word3>.<word4|word5>.anyword.(any word containing proj in it)
```

I tried

```
Solution.\b(word1|word2|word3)\b.\b(word4|word5)\b.(.*).\b(.*proj)\b
```

But this allows strings like `Solution.word1.word4.blabla.blabla.csproj`, meaning it allows anything before the proj because of the .*.

Can someone help me with this??

Comment: yep, you get the match because of `csproj` contains the word `proj`

Comment: This statement `"any word containing proj in it"` is seemingly a contradiction to a string like `csproj`. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need this regex:

```
Solution\.(word1|word2|word3)\.(word4|word5)\.([^.]+)\..*?\bproj\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM8yY7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try (need to escape the `.` and allow capturing group to have chars except `.`):

```
Solution\.\b(word1|word2|word3)\b\.\b(word4|word5)\b\.([^\.]*)\.\b([^\.]*proj)\b
```

Comment: Cool. Merry Christmas to you too :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to consider the actual strings you want to allow without more clarification.

You can try the following regular expression.

```
Solution\.word[123]\.word[45]\.\w+\.\w*proj\b
```

Comment: Not exactly this but I recognize that I might have formatted the question in a weird way thanks for you help! Merry Christmas!